# Can the chain rule be proven by math induction?

Tags: derivatives, induction

I need to prove the chain rule for a math project and I am wondering if it can be proven by math induction. If not, how can this rule be proven?

Comment: As in, $(f\circ g)'=f'\circ g g'$? Definitely not. Mathematical induction is for proving something holds for every natural $n$. As to how it can be proven, there are probably over a thousand proofs published across the Internet, so there's no reason for us to repeat one here-just Google it.

Comment: Induction is incompatible for this. However, you can look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) for a proof.

Comment: You can read ANY real analysis book, there will be a prove there.

Comment: Induction usually proves a statement for all integers greater than or equal to some "base case" value. I'm not sure how this would apply to the chain rule, since no integers are involved.

Comment: I don't think math.stackexchange attempts to avoid duplicating content that can be found elsewhere on the internet or in books. However, proofs of the chain rule can be found on math.stackexchange itself.

Comment: @MirandaChristenson Do you mean with [transfinite induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction)?

Comment: Maybe an inductive proof could be made when $f,g$ are polynomials.

Comment: Perhaps the intent is the *multivariable* chain rule? That could technically be proven by induction, although it would be uglier than necessary.

Comment: There seems to be a pretty neat looking proof in the calculus textbook I used (James Stewart, Early Transcendentals, 7th Edition) It's at the end of section 3.6. Don't know if it is what you are looking for(I don't have a very strong mathematics background, so maybe you want something more rigorous with upside down As and the like, but it made sense to me). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I will outline a proof here that is really adapted from an old calculus text by James Stewart. This is not from an analysis book but from a standard calculus text; thus, the rigor is still maintained but not quite as terse. A proof from Rudin is offered at the end for a different style.

---

**Prefatory comments:** Recall that if $y=f(x)$ and $x$ changes from $a$ to $a+\Delta x$, we define the increment of $y$ as
$$
\Delta y=f(a+\Delta x)-f(a).
$$
According to the definition of a derivative, we have
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=f'(a).
$$
So if we denote by $\epsilon$ the difference between the difference quotient and the derivative, we obtain
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\epsilon = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-f'(a)\right)=f'(a)-f'(a)=0.
$$
But
$$
\epsilon=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-f'(a)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\Delta y = f'(a)\Delta x+\epsilon\Delta x.

If we define $\epsilon$ to be $0$ when $\Delta x=0$, then $\epsilon$ becomes a continuous function of $\Delta x$. Thus, for a differentiable function $f$, we can write
$$
\Delta y=f'(a)\Delta x+\epsilon\Delta x\quad\text{where}\quad\epsilon\to 0\quad\text{as}\quad\Delta x\to 0,\tag{1}
$$
and $\epsilon$ is a continuous function of $\Delta x$. This property of differentiable functions is what enables us to prove the Chain Rule.

---

**Proof:** Suppose $u=g(x)$ is differentiable at $a$ and $y=f(u)$ is differentiable at $b=g(a)$. If $\Delta x$ is an increment in $x$ and $\Delta u$ and $\Delta y$ are the corresponding increments in $u$ and $y$, then we can use equation $(1)$ to write
$$
\Delta u=g'(a)\Delta x+\epsilon_1\Delta x=[g'(a)+\epsilon_1]\Delta x,\tag{2}
$$
where $\epsilon_1\to 0$ as $\Delta x\to 0$. Similarly,
$$
\Delta y = f'(b)\Delta u+\epsilon_2\Delta u=[f'(b)+\epsilon_2]\Delta u,\tag{3}
$$
where $\epsilon_2\to 0$ as $\Delta u\to 0$. If we now substitute the expression for $\Delta u$ from equation $(2)$ into equation $(3)$, we get
$$
\Delta y=[f'(b)+\epsilon_2][g'(a)+\epsilon_1]\Delta x
$$
so
$$
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=[f'(b)+\epsilon_2][g'(a)+\epsilon_1].
$$
As $\Delta x\to 0$, equation $(2)$ shows that $\Delta u\to 0$. So both $\epsilon_1\to0$ and $\epsilon_2\to0$ as $\Delta x\to 0$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\\[1em]
              &= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}[f'(b)+\epsilon_2][g'(a)+\epsilon_1]\\[1em]
              &= f'(b)g'(a)=f'(g(a))g'(a).
\end{align}
This proves the Chain Rule (see below for a much more terse treatment). $\Box$

---

**Proof of Chain Rule in Baby Rudin:** The Chain Rule is first stated as a theorem:

**Theorem.** Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b], f'(x)$ exists at some point $x\in[a,b], g$ is defined on an interval $I$ which contains the range of $f$, and $g$ is differentiable at the point $f(x)$. If
$$
h(t) = g(f(t))\qquad(a\leq t\leq b),
$$
then $h$ is differentiable at $x$, and 
$$
h'(x) = g'(f(x))f'(x).\tag{1}
$$

**Proof.** Let $y=f(x)$. By the definition of the derivative, we have
$$
f(t)-f(x)=(t-x)[f'(x)+u(t)],\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
g(s)-g(y)=(s-y)[g'(y)+v(s)],\tag{3}
$$
where $t\in[a,b], s\in I$, and $u(t)\to 0$ as $t\to x, v(s)\to 0$ as $s\to y$. Let $s=f(t)$. Using first $(3)$ and $(2)$, we obtain
\begin{align}
h(t)-h(x) &= g(f(t))-g(f(x))\\
          &= [f(t)-f(x)]\cdot[g'(y)+v(s)]\\
          &= (t-x)\cdot[f'(x)+u(t)]\cdot[g'(y)+v(s)],
\end{align}
or, if $t\neq x$,
$$
\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}=[g'(y)+v(s)]\cdot[f'(x)+u(t)].\tag{4}
$$
Letting $t\to x$, we see that $s\to y$, by the continuity of $f$, so that the right side of $(4)$ tend to $g'(y)f'(x)$, which gives $(1)$. $\Box$

Comment: Note also there's nice intuition for the chain rule.  If $f(x) = g(h(x))$, then $f(x + \Delta x) = g(h(x + \Delta x)) \approx g(h(x) + h'(x) \Delta x) \approx g(h(x)) + g'(h(x)) h'(x) \Delta x$.  To make this into a rigorous proof, we only need to keep track of the errors in the approximations, and show that they are sufficiently small (in some sense).